# Provided read-in file for survey data in R error

Tags: r, survey

I'm trying to use survey data from the FDIC 2019 survey of the unbanked. Their dataset download has an R read-in file that I was able to use last year, but no longer works. The zip file containing data and read-in file can be [found on this site](https://www.fdic.gov/analysis/household-survey/data-downloads/index.html) or downloaded directly with [this link](https://www.fdic.gov/analysis/household-survey/data-downloads/hh2019.zip).

When I attempt to run the first example that appears at the bottom of the read-in file:

```
svyby(~hunbnk,~hryear4,hh_svy,svymean )
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in sum(sapply(covmats, ncol)) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I believe there may be an issue with the [labeling of factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275950/svyby-returns-error-although-arguments-match-documentation), but I'm not familiar enough to know how to correct it, or why it suddenly doesn't work. Likewise, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling packages such as survey and sqldf, but it still throws an error. I'm hoping to obtain weighted mean subset data from the dataset, but don't have access to other programs to read the data.

Comment: You're getting that error because one of the elements of covmats is a list, and `ncol()` doesn't work on lists. It's advisable to avoid `sapply`, which is an unpredictable function. Because 'covmats' contains a list, it must itself be a list, so it would be better to use `lapply` - you will get the same error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this code to the top of the file helped it run. Looks like a newer version of R caused the read-in file to fail.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, `svyby` cares about the difference between factors and character strings, and here (as in most cases) the user wants factors, which have a known set of levels, rather than strings.  In version 4.2 of the survey package there will be a `stringsAsFactors` argument to `svyby`, defaulting to `TRUE` to convert all strings passed in to factors. That's overkill (and a bit slow) but it seems to be necessary after the changes to R.

Answer (score 1):

the `applyFormats()` function that the wrote isn't applying the labels properly: notice that after running it, `table(hh$hsupresp)` still gives zero one rather than labeled values.  and then when it hits `hh=subset(hh,hsupresp=='Respondent')` ..it subsets out every record.  ultimately, that results in the problem below and also the error message you're seeing.

```
> nrow(hh)
[1] 0
> nrow(hh_svy)
[1] 0
```

if you revise that subset line, you can see actual results?  maybe send them a note and let them know their 2019 value labelmaker needs a slight fix?

```
hh<-read.csv("hh2019_analys.csv",na.strings=".")
hh=applyFormats(hh)
hh=subset(hh,hsupresp==1)
hh_svy <- svydesign(id=~1, weights=~h,data=hh,repweights =hh[,grepl("repwgt.*",names(hh)) & !grepl("repwgt0.*",names(hh))  ],type="JKn",scale = 0.025, rscales=rep(1, 160),combined.weights=TRUE)
svyby(~hunbnk,~hryear4,hh_svy,svymean )
```